# Dative prepositions and reflexive pronoun

Tags: preposition, pronoun, dative, reflexive

> Bitte melden Sie sich bis zum 10. Juni per Mail oder telefonisch an.

In this sentence there are 2 prepositions together *bis* and *zum*, there is a reflexive pronoun and *an* is at the last of the sentence even through *anmelden* is not a separable verb.

Please tell me what does this sentence mean literally and otherwise, and the rule of grammar behind the sentence structure.

Comment: Sorry, but "anmelden" is of course a separable verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence means
"Please register until 10th july via mail or telephone."

"bis zum" literally translates to "until to the (day)". The sentence would also work without the "zum".

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply,  what does *Sie sich  and an at the last means and why is that so.

Comment: anmelden = to register is reflexive, it can not stand on its own. So you need to register yourself. "Bitte melden Sie sich an" = Please register yourself

Comment: But be aware that "Mail" in a German sentence generally means e-mail, so the translation is not completely accurate.